# Gitlab. Using gitlab-ci-token and $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY cause error

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been using gitlab.com for about 1 year. I didn't do any changes and I started to get the such error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

The command I use:

```
 - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you want `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` not `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` -- unless you're defining the `CI_BUILD_TOKEN` variable yourself somewhere.

Comment: @sytech I don't know where you find this information, but it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, I have found it in the Removals and breaking changes. section here https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$CI_BUILD_TOKEN`, along with all other `CI_BUILD_*` variables, were [deprecated in GitLab v9.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/352957/?_gl=1*4gqibn*_ga*MTQxMTgwMjg2Mi4xNjc0NTI0MjA4*_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y*MTY4NDg3Mzc0My4xMTkuMS4xNjg0ODc1NDkxLjAuMC4w) (Mar 2017) and removed in GitLab 16.0 (May 22 2023) and is replaced by `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`.

So you'll want to change your script to update this variable:

```yaml
 - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```